# Vaadin breaks spring-boot-devtools reload

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin

I'm trying out Vaadin for a few days now and the most annoying thing is that spring-boot-devtools always fails to properly reload my project since I added Vaadin to it and created a simple View. (it is originally a Thymeleaf MVC project)

If I remove Vaadin and comment out the classes I've created, everything is back to normal. Not being able to reload is quite annoying since the project is very dependent of Spring Security.

This is what I get when I recompile the project, causing devtools to reload:

```
2017-02-03 09:30:14.034 DEBUG 10528 --- [Thread-7] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'requestContextFilter'
2017-02-03 09:30:14.034 DEBUG 10528 --- [Thread-7] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'objectPostProcessor': [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration, org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration, authenticationManagerBuilder, org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration, h2ConsoleSecurityConfigurer]
2017-02-03 09:30:14.049 DEBUG 10528 --- [Thread-7] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration': [h2ConsoleSecurityConfigurer, authenticationManager]
2017-02-03 09:30:14.049 DEBUG 10528 --- [Thread-7] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'objectPostProcessor'
2017-02-03 09:30:14.049 DEBUG 10528 --- [Thread-7] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'validator': [methodValidationPostProcessor]
2017-02-03 09:30:14.049 DEBUG 10528 --- [Thread-7] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'validator'
2017-02-03 09:30:14.049 DEBUG 10528 --- [Thread-7] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor'
2017-02-03 09:30:14.049 DEBUG 10528 --- [Thread-7] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory': [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor]
2017-02-03 09:30:14.143 DEBUG 10528 --- [localhost-startStop-2] c.v.spring.internal.UIScopeImpl$UIStore  : Vaadin service has been destroyed, destroying [UIStore[id=230d8019, sessionId=8C47AB9C565C8E7D8BF706C1F2C84801]]
2017-02-03 09:30:14.143 DEBUG 10528 --- [localhost-startStop-2] com.vaadin.spring.internal.BeanStore     : Destroying [UIBeanStore[id=61ef3d51, name=UI:0]]
2017-02-03 09:30:14.143 DEBUG 10528 --- [localhost-startStop-2] .s.c.a.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Invoking destroy method on bean 'viewCache': void com.vaadin.spring.internal.DefaultViewCache.destroy()
2017-02-03 09:30:14.143 DEBUG 10528 --- [localhost-startStop-2] com.vaadin.spring.internal.BeanStore     : Destroying [ViewBeanStore[id=50572723, name=null:]]
2017-02-03 09:30:14.143  WARN 10528 --- [localhost-startStop-2] .s.c.a.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'viewCache'

2017-02-03 09:30:14.143 DEBUG 10528 --- [localhost-startStop-2] c.v.spring.internal.UIScopeImpl$UIStore  : Vaadin service has been destroyed, destroying [UIStore[id=230d8019, sessionId=8C47AB9C565C8E7D8BF706C1F2C84801]]
2017-02-03 09:30:14.143 DEBUG 10528 --- [localhost-startStop-2] com.vaadin.spring.internal.BeanStore     : Destroying [UIBeanStore[id=61ef3d51, name=UI:0]]
2017-02-03 09:30:14.143 DEBUG 10528 --- [localhost-startStop-2] .s.c.a.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Invoking destroy method on bean 'viewCache': void com.vaadin.spring.internal.DefaultViewCache.destroy()
2017-02-03 09:30:14.143 DEBUG 10528 --- [localhost-startStop-2] com.vaadin.spring.internal.BeanStore     : Destroying [ViewBeanStore[id=50572723, name=null:]]
2017-02-03 09:30:14.143  WARN 10528 --- [localhost-startStop-2] .s.c.a.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'viewCache'

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.vaadin.spring.internal.DefaultViewCache.destroy(DefaultViewCache.java:196) ~[vaadin-spring-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeDestroyMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:325) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeDestruction(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:154) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253) [spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.run(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:246) [spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at com.vaadin.spring.internal.BeanStore.destroy(BeanStore.java:101) [vaadin-spring-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at com.vaadin.spring.internal.SessionLockingBeanStore.destroy(SessionLockingBeanStore.java:66) [vaadin-spring-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at com.vaadin.spring.internal.UIScopeImpl$UIStore.destroy(UIScopeImpl.java:237) [vaadin-spring-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at com.vaadin.spring.internal.UIScopeImpl$UIStore.serviceDestroy(UIScopeImpl.java:247) [vaadin-spring-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508) [vaadin-server-7.6.8.jar:7.6.8]
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198) [vaadin-server-7.6.8.jar:7.6.8]
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161) [vaadin-server-7.6.8.jar:7.6.8]
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.destroy(VaadinService.java:1893) [vaadin-server-7.6.8.jar:7.6.8]
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.destroy(VaadinServlet.java:1360) [vaadin-server-7.6.8.jar:7.6.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.unload(StandardWrapper.java:1340) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.stopInternal(StandardWrapper.java:1671) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5399) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1435) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1424) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_112]

2017-02-03 09:30:14.721 DEBUG 10528 --- [Thread-7] o.s.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter      : Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@445380be
2017-02-03 09:30:14.721 DEBUG 10528 --- [Thread-7] o.s.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter      : Starting application com.marcelustrojahn.agile.configuration.Application with URLs [file:/E:/Development/marcelustrojahn/agile-crm/target/    classes/]
2017-02-03 09:30:14.877 DEBUG 10528 --- [restartedMain] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application started with classpath: [file:/E:/Development/marcelustrojahn/agile-crm/target/classes/]
2017-02-03 09:30:14.877 DEBUG 10528 --- [restartedMain] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Could not find key 'context.listener.classes' in any property source
2017-02-03 09:30:14.877 DEBUG 10528 --- [restartedMain] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Could not find key 'banner.image.location' in any property source
2017-02-03 09:30:14.877 DEBUG 10528 --- [restartedMain] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Could not find key 'banner.location' in any property source
2017-02-03 09:30:14.877 DEBUG 10528 --- [restartedMain] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2017-02-03 09:30:14.877 DEBUG 10528 --- [restartedMain] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2017-02-03 09:30:14.877 DEBUG 10528 --- [restartedMain] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2017-02-03 09:30:14.877 DEBUG 10528 --- [restartedMain] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2017-02-03 09:30:14.877 DEBUG 10528 --- [restartedMain] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [    servletConfigInitParams,servletContextInitParams,systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
2017-02-03 09:30:14.877 DEBUG 10528 --- [restartedMain] o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner   : JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
2017-02-03 09:30:14.893 DEBUG 10528 --- [restartedMain] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Could not find key 'context.initializer.classes' in any property source
2017-02-03 09:30:14.893 DEBUG 10528 --- [restartedMain] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Could not find key 'spring.config.name:application' in any property source
2017-02-03 09:30:14.893 DEBUG 10528 --- [restartedMain] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Could not find key 'spring.config.name' in any property source
2017-02-03 09:30:14.893 DEBUG 10528 --- [restartedMain] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Could not find key 'vcap.application.name:application' in any property source
2017-02-03 09:30:14.893 DEBUG 10528 --- [restartedMain] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Could not find key 'vcap.application.name' in any property source
2017-02-03 09:30:14.893 DEBUG 10528 --- [restartedMain] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Could not find key 'spring.application.name:application' in any property source
2017-02-03 09:30:14.909 DEBUG 10528 --- [restartedMain] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Could not find key 'spring.application.name' in any property source
2017-02-03 09:30:14.909 DEBUG 10528 --- [restartedMain] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Could not find key 'PORT:null' in any property source
2017-02-03 09:30:14.909 DEBUG 10528 --- [restartedMain] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Could not find key 'PORT' in any property source
2017-02-03 09:30:14.909 DEBUG 10528 --- [restartedMain] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Could not find key 'server.port:null' in any property source
2017-02-03 09:30:14.909 DEBUG 10528 --- [restartedMain] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Could not find key 'server.port' in any property source
2017-02-03 09:30:14.909 DEBUG 10528 --- [restartedMain] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Could not find key 'spring.application.index:null' in any property source
2017-02-03 09:30:14.909 DEBUG 10528 --- [restartedMain] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Could not find key 'spring.application.index' in any property source
2017-02-03 09:30:14.909 DEBUG 10528 --- [restartedMain] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Could not find key 'vcap.application.instance_index:null' in any property source
2017-02-03 09:30:14.909 DEBUG 10528 --- [restartedMain] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Could not find key 'vcap.application.instance_index' in any property source
2017-02-03 09:30:14.909 DEBUG 10528 --- [restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Registering scope 'restart' with implementation [org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartScopeInitializer$RestartScope@9929720]
2017-02-03 09:30:14.909 DEBUG 10528 --- [restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
2017-02-03 09:30:14.909  INFO 10528 --- [restartedMain] c.m.agile.configuration.Application      : Starting Application on DESKTOP-P5AO315 with PID 10528
```

Comment: Worth reporting to them I think, see https://github.com/vaadin/spring/issues

Comment: I have fought this problem as well, only working solution i found was to use jRebel.

Comment: As @StephaneNicoll said, please fill in an issue. Hopefully you can also deliver a project that can be used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, all... I opened a ticket but, unfortunately, I created a new project to try to reproduce the issue and it doesn't happen... My guess it's something very specific related to spring-security and the vaadin session. As for JRebel, I guess I'll go back to it and try again... I left it because the 7.0 version of the Intellij IDEA plugin was also not reloading correctly some other project.